# Showing last calls inside android app in Google Privacy Policy compliant way

Tags: android, android-contacts, policy, calllog

I've got an app which shows user's contacts inside device and allows him to make a call.
I want to show my user the last calls he has made. I was using `READ_CALL_LOG` permission (and was reading call log) until Google restricted access to it, then I switched to `ContactsProvider` to retrieve contacts and sort them by `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` but now Google says this column is deprecated and effectively it will have 0 value for new versions of Android OS (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#ObsoleteData)

My app is not a default dialer (only default dialers apps are allowed to access call log) so I was wondering how I can achieve what I want in Google Policy compliant way.

I tought about storing the last contacts selected inside my own database (I know it won't be a full call log, as I will only have access to calls made from my app but that's fine for me), but don't know whether it's compliant with G Policy. I wrote an email to Google, however the person who replied said he can't help me with my question and I have to create new version of my app and ask them for review.

Does anyone know if my idea about saving contacts in my own database is compliant with G policy (please provide links from official sites). From my link (which I've provided above) I can only see that Google says

> If your apps are accessing or updating these fields or APIs, use
>   alternative methods. For example, you can fulfill certain use cases by
>   using private content providers or other data stored within your app
>   or backend systems.

However it doesn't convince me to whether my idea is compliant

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may store and use any user actions that had happened within your app.
The purpose of the policy (as stated here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en) is to prevent apps from getting access to the call-log in order to make use of it for purposes other then what users' expect, that's why the emphasis on `critical core functionality` of the app.

In my experience, different Google reviewers tend to review the same app very differently, and while one may reject a certain use-case based on this policy, another might approve it.

I would suggest phrasing the screen you want to create in a way that will help the reviewer understand that this data was not acquired from the call-log but some app specific actions, so for example instead of title "Call Log" which might confuse some reviewers with the risk of rejecting this update, you should title it "Recent app actions" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know when exactly reviewer checks my app, and if it's not compliant would I get a warning first or my app may be immediately removed from the Play Store?

Comment: if this is an update to an existing app, the review will reject *the update* not the app itself, we had to go through many review cycles with Google until our update was approved after this policy went into affect, but our production version remained live.

Comment: but if I'm not using any sensitive permission do I still get any review? I tought it's only for apps which access permissions like READ_CALL_LOG

Comment: right, that's why there's no problem with using actions performed in your own app. you're not accessing any sensitive info on the device, and don't need any special permissions.